# Error: Argument passed to call that takes no arguments SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

In my code I get this error and I cannot figure out how to resolve it. The error is in the Trailing block of code

```
struct Map: View {
    
    @ObservedObject public var dataManager = DataManager.shared
    
    @Binding public var seqId: String
    
    // rz- to pass seqId to second view
    //   @State public var seqId2: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Results").foregroundColor(Color.white).onAppear{self.dataManager.downloadSeqData(seqId: self.seqId)}                        .onAppear(perform: playSound)/*rz want to add this sound func to contentview somehow, otherwise it will constantly play sound when page loads */ .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                
                //rz- if strand is linear draw line
                if dataManager.dataSet?.INSDSeq.topology == "linear" {
                    
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.black)
                    .frame(width: 500, height: 20)
                }
                //rz- if strand is circular draw o
                if dataManager.dataSet?.INSDSeq.topology == "circular" {
                Circle()
                    .stroke(Color.black, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 20, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                    .frame(width: 500, height: 500)
                }
                if dataManager.dataSet?.INSDSeq.topology != "circular" && dataManager.dataSet?.INSDSeq.topology != "linear"{
                    Text("Data Unavailable, try a new accession number.")
                }
            }
                
            .navigationBarItems(
    //rz - added home and genbank view to navigation bars
                leading:
                    NavigationLink(destination: ContentView()) {
                           Text("New Query")
                               .font(.title)
                               .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                        },

                trailing:
                    NavigationLink(destination: Screen(seqId: self.$seqId)) {
                      Text("GenBank View")
                          .font(.title)
                          .foregroundColor(Color.black)
```

Error is in `$seqId`

```
NavigationLink(destination: Screen(seqId: self.$seqId)) {
```

Here is the Screen view

```
import SwiftUI


struct Screen: View {


@ObservedObject public var dataManager = DataManager.shared
@State private var seqId: String = ""

var body: some View {
    VStack {
       TextField("Enter Accession Number", text: $seqId)
        .padding()
        
        Button("Search")
        {
        dataManager.downloadSeqData(seqId: seqId)
            
            
           }
        
        
        ScrollView {

        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
           
                    
                Text(dataManager.dataSet?.INSDSeq.locus ?? "")
                    .padding()
                Text(dataManager.dataSet?.INSDSeq.organism ?? "").padding()
                Text(dataManager.dataSet?.INSDSeq.source ?? "").padding()
                Text(dataManager.dataSet?.INSDSeq.taxonomy ?? "").padding()
                Text(dataManager.dataSet?.INSDSeq.topology ?? "").padding()
                Text(dataManager.dataSet?.INSDSeq.length == nil ? "" : "\(dataManager.dataSet!.INSDSeq.length)") .padding()
                Text(dataManager.dataSet?.INSDSeq.strandedness ?? "").padding()
                Text(dataManager.dataSet?.INSDSeq.moltype ?? "").padding()
                Text(dataManager.dataSet?.INSDSeq.sequence ?? "").padding()
            
            }
            
            .cornerRadius(10)
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                ForEach(dataManager.featureList, id:\.self) { feature in
                    
                    VStack (alignment: .leading){
                        VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                            Text(feature.INSDFeature_key).bold()
                            Text(feature.INSDFeature_location)
                        }.padding()
                    
                        IntervalSection(feature: feature)
                        
                        QualsSection(feature: feature)
                        
                    }
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                }
            }
            
            .cornerRadius(20)
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
                    
    }
    
    }
    
    }



struct IntervalSection: View {
var feature: INSDFeature
var body: some View {
    VStack (alignment: .leading){
        ForEach(0..<feature.INSDFeature_intervals.count, id: \.self) { i in
            ForEach(0..<feature.INSDFeature_intervals[i].INSDInterval.count, id: \.self) { j in
                if let from = feature.INSDFeature_intervals[i].INSDInterval[j].INSDInterval_from {
                    VStack (alignment: .leading){
                        Text("\(from)").bold()
                        Text("\(feature.INSDFeature_intervals[i].INSDInterval[j].INSDInterval_to ?? -1)")
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}

struct QualsSection: View{
var feature: INSDFeature
var body: some View {
    VStack (alignment: .leading){
        ForEach(0..<feature.INSDFeature_quals.count , id: \.self) { i in
            ForEach(0..<feature.INSDFeature_quals[i].INSDQualifier.count , id: \.self) { j in
                VStack (alignment: .leading){
                    Text(feature.INSDFeature_quals[i].INSDQualifier[j].INSDQualifier_name).bold()
                    Text(feature.INSDFeature_quals[i].INSDQualifier[j].INSDQualifier_value)
                }
                .padding()
                .cornerRadius(10)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: And what is `Screen`? What does the `init` method look like for `Screen`?  Most likely you don't have such an init.

Comment: Screen is the content view that displays the information in a list format.  There is no init method in the screen page

Comment: Too much trouble to post the code? What properties does it have, there is always an synthesised init if it is a struct which I assume it is.

Comment: just uploaded it

Comment: And the view doesn't take a seqId as parameter since that property is private (and is a `@State` variable). It looks to me that the Screen view doesn't need to be initialised with seqId as it takes it as input? Otherwise you need to change it to `@Binding` and remove private

Answer (score 1):

In SwiftUI you should use `Binding` instead of `State` in cases, where the data is coming from another view. Furthermore both attributes of `Screen` are private, therefore they can't be accessed in this case set from outside of the struct itself.

I would suggest to make `seqID` in `Screen` public like you did it with `dataManager` and change it to `State`